# react-leaflet <GeoJSON /> pointToLayer option to change the icon

Tags: react-leaflet

i am currently trying to learn react and i want to use a leaflet map (react-leaflet).

I have two (Point, Polygon) GeoJson objects that i want to display, which is working, but i want to replace the default marker icon.

The leaflet documentation http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ tells me to use the pointToLayer option.

Code:

onEachFeaturePoint, onEachfeaturePolygon, pointToLayer

```
onEachFeaturePoint(feature, layer) {
  console.log('feature: ', feature);
  console.log('layer: ', layer);
  layer.on({
    'click': function (e) {
       console.log('e: ', e);
       console.log('click');
     }
  })
}

onEachFeaturePolygon(feature, layer) {
  console.log('feature: ', feature);
  console.log('layer: ', layer);
  layer.on({
    'click': function (e) {
       console.log('e: ', e);
       console.log('click');
     }
  })
}

pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
  console.log('--- Point to layer');
  console.log('feature: ', feature);
  console.log('latlng: ', latlng);
  return <CircleMarker center={latlng} />;
}
```

render

```
render() {
  const center = [9.4921875, 51.83577752045248];

  return (
    <Map center={center} zoom={1}>
      <GeoJSON ref='marker1' data={this.state.point} onEachFeature={this.onEachFeaturePoint.bind(this)} pointToLayer={this.pointToLayer.bind(this)} />
      <GeoJSON ref='polygon1' data={this.state.polygon} onEachFeature={this.onEachFeaturePolygon.bind(this)} />
    </Map>
  )
}
```

If i keep `pointToLayer={this.pointToLayer.bind(this)}` it stops working with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: layer.on is not a function
    at CustomMarker.onEachFeaturePoint (MapDemo.js:73)
    at NewClass.addData (leaflet-src.js:10455)
    at NewClass.addData (leaflet-src.js:10435)
    at NewClass.initialize (leaflet-src.js:10420)
    at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js:310)
    at L.geoJSON (leaflet-src.js:10732)
```

I cant figure out why the error occurs, maybe someone has an idea how to solve this issue or help my understand the mistakes i made.

**Edit:** By replacing `return <CirleMarker />` with `return L.circleMarker()` in the `pointToLayer` function, i got it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By replacing `return <CirleMarker />` with `return L.circleMarker()` in the `pointToLayer` function, i got it to work.

```
import L from 'leaflet';

...

pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
   return L.circleMarker(latlng, null); // Change marker to circle
   // return L.marker(latlng, { icon: {}}); // Change the icon to a custom icon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off trying to use the Marker component instead of the GeoJSON component if you're simply trying to display a custom icon.

```
<Map center={center} zoom={1}>
  <Marker
    icon={homeIcon}
    key='marker1'
    onClick={this._handleClick}
    position={leafletLatLng}
    />
</Map>

...

const homeIconUrl = 'home-2.png'
const homeIcon = icon({
  iconUrl: homeIconUrl,
  iconSize: [32, 37],
  iconAnchor: [16, 37]
})
```

Comment: I got it to work by using `L.circleMarker()` instead of `<CircleMarker />` in the `pointToLayer` function.

Comment: Do you thing there could be a way to use a React like syntax instead?